# ¿ Is there a spherical geometry XML namespace to use with SVG …?

Tags: javascript, math, svg, vegan

I am working to reduce size of an [Equirectangular map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-Equirectangular.svg), losslessly. Upon optimizing the SVG images with use of [an online tool](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) I am unsure whether any of the shapes overlap (hereby in this state of matter asserting a reality that is either conflicting or less relevant). Regardless of any one of the processing methods which applies to this image, I am simply assuming that multiplicity of straight(ened) lines among coordinates on the given map are best optimized with use of polynomial functions, composites and/or derivates thereof (such as splines or bezier curves, as defined with XML/SVG).

I am looking for a list of mathematical methods to use -- in order to figure out points where any of the neighbouring SVG polygons overlap. I expect to transform shapes upon discovering the most proper mathematics, so that two polynoms of any two shapes on map will only intersect in one point, at most (most likely so). In other words, any intersection will not exceed an area of zero and will match properties of either a zero-dimensional object (a point), or an infinite and limited series thereof (a line).

````js
// See me write best code, because this is like the yellow cake topping of global standards

Import {
 Uniform_Resource_Identifier as URI,
 Uniform_Resource_Locator as URL
} from "@jsonion/RegularExpressions://wikipedia/en";

Import {
 QualifiedName as QName
} from "@jsonion://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/qnameids"

Import {
 Optional as Opt
} from "@jsonion://github.com/aldeed/simpl-schema"

Import { parseType, evaluateArgs, oneOf } from "jsonion/lib"

//
// Behind the scenes is a seamless SVGn archive of ```js onion ˙˙˙ sliced domesticated codebase from the interwebs
// … the sky's an umbrella term to everything we know & it comes in the shape of thy heartest sun -- there really is no end to it
//
// Look, a meteor shower surrounds a light source and its satellite
//  .*  //

var jsonion = {
 loadRes: function (args, inputSchema = {
  expr: "loadResource",
__location: { 
  uri: [URI, QName, oneOf],
  href: [URL], 
  ...oneOf 
  },
  mirror: [URL, Opt]
 })
 {
   /* … */

   return ( var err = evaluateArgs( args, inputSchema ) 
   ? err.push("Li{B") 
   : "undefined" // … brb, get me a postMessage() method native to foreignObject
 },
 findMeOverlappingShapes: ( args = {
  asd: "sdf",
  foo: "bar"
 }) =>
 {

 }
}
````

May I kindly request for this favour -- so to compile a JS fiddle or a Git commit which I can recall with ease of mind and think about, even while I do seemingly unrelated stuff (ie. slicing onions for a vegan pizza).

Can you please forward to me some of the fine online sources, whether be it aligned with any or all of the following... one that you would cite yourself; one with a good example (and corridors to lead through gaps of interlaced but distinct knowledge bodies); one that you expect to stay online and maintained for the longer period of time (with a disambiguation protocol for future reference)

I don't spell out mathematics as much as I do web coding, so thank you all so much!

*PS, I will share my recipe for a cheese pizza topping which doesn't boil in a heated oven, embedded in the forementioned code pen/snippet, as promised
… that's a fully vegan or an ovo-vegetarian recipe, but of course I'll choose one of these types only after I study and understand sources in reference*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Comment: http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/venation.sig2005.pdf

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Function_definition

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Tasks

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: https://github.com/stamen/modestmaps-js

Comment: https://github.com/NotWoods/spherical-geometry-js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feTurbulence

Comment: http://adrianb.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html

Comment: http://caniuse.com http://modernizr.com/download

Comment: https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/blob/master/velocity.js#L1626(getComputedStyle)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473936/how-to-animate-svg-paths-as-an-animated-pdf-with-animate

Comment: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-is-poier-and-jensens-bond-capacity-model-parameterized-and-optimized?rq=1

Comment: https://v2.parceljs.org/blog/beta3/